# react native modal unmounted when invisible modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I build react native app and I have modal, when the modal is close and visible = false so it call unmounted and then the ref of the modal is undefined and I can't use the modal again.

part of my modal

```
componentDidMount() {
    try {
        this.props.onRef(this)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('willunmount')
    this.props.onRef(undefined)
}
    setModalInvisible = async () => {
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.valueC,
        {
            toValue: 200,
            duration: 800
        }).start(() => {

            AppStore.hideAppointmentPopup()
            this.state.valueC.setValue(0)



        })

}
    render() {

        let { valueC, date, service_type, time, popupType } = this.state

        margin = valueC.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 100, 200],
            outputRange: [-screenHeight, 0, screenHeight]
        }),
            opacity = valueC.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 100, 200],
                outputRange: [0, 1, 0]
            })
        const { popup, container, btnIconClose, iconClose, viewIconClose, viewTextContent, textStyleHeader, textStyleSuccess, textStyleWaiting, viewBtn, submitButton, buttonText } = style;

        return (
            <Modal animationType='fade' transparent={true}
                visible={AppStore.appointmentPopupVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => { this.setModalInvisible() }}>
                <View style={style.container}>

                    <Animated.View style={[style.popup, { marginTop: margin, opacity: opacity }]}>
                        {/* <Button style={btnIconClose} onPress={() => { this.setModalInvisible() }} >
                            <Icon name="close" size={calcSize(45)} color={colors.black} style={iconClose} />
                        </Button> */}
                        {this.renderPopupByType(popupType)}


                        <View style={viewBtn}>
                            <RoundButton text='CLOSE' disabled={false} textStyle={buttonText} style={submitButton} onPress={this.setModalInvisible} />
                        </View>
                    </Animated.View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

then in other screen when i want to use it

```
import { Header,AppointmentPopup } from '../../components';
let popupOpen = false

@inject('AppStore','NavigationStore') @observer
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            appState: AppState.currentState,
            nowMounted: false

        }
        this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this)

    }

    goBack() {
        console.log(this.props.NavigationStore.AppCurrentRoute)
        this.props.NavigationStore.appGoBack(true)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ nowMounted: true })
    }






    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Header  header={this.props.NavigationStore.HeaderTitle} onPressBack={this.goBack}/>
                <AppointmentPopup onRef={(ref) => { this.appointmentPopupRef = ref; this.props.AppStore.setAppointmentPopupRef(ref) }} />

                <AppStack  />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

when i want to use it with ref
**this.appointmentPopupRef** it show me undefined because I close the modal and I don't have any option to use it again. just when I close the app and open again. how I can prevent the modal to use unmounted?
If I remove it

```
   componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.onRef(undefined)
    }
```

so it show me error

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the _class component.

Comment: There is another problem in your code, probably the part that you didn't share, by default your `AppointmentPopup` component never unmounted after hiding, checkout example: https://snack.expo.io/@amirdew/popup-will-unmount

Comment: weird. what can be my problem?

Comment: try by commenting extra lines like "AppStore.hideAppointmentPopup()", valueC, etc

Comment: okay I found the problem. I declare AppointmentPopup in two different screen.